# Avoiding ambiguity when using pronouns to refer back to different parts of the preceding clause

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I have the following sentence

> A Terminal Interface is used to interact with the Operating
> System that acts as an intermediary between the user and the
> computer hardware.

I want to make sure that the operating system would be interpreted as the intermediary, and not the Terminal Interface.  But do not know whether my sentence might cause confusion.

Should I rewrite it and how would the modification look like?

Comment: I would not close this question because it is an example of a common problem and many others will profit from the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a good illustration of a grammatical problem many beginners face: How to refer to specific parts of a preceding clause.

As a demonstrative pronoun, *that* introduces a restrictive relative clause and serves as a substitute within that clause for the substantive modified by the clause. In other words, the clause following *that* explains the word or phrase **that immediately precedes it**, in this case "operating system".

If you want to refer back to the subject of the preceding clause (in your case "terminal interface"), you would use a personal pronoun, in your case "it" (as interface is a thing, not a person). You could do that in two ways:

> A Terminal Interface is used to interact with the Operating
> System ***and it*** acts as an intermediary between the user and the computer hardware.
>
> A Terminal Interface is used to interact with the Operating
> System. **It** acts as an intermediary between the user and the computer hardware.

But since you want to refer back to the prase that precedes the pronoun, you need to use "that". That is, **the example as you give it is correct and means what you want it to mean.**

Comment: Would you know of a good rule book for grammar I can read ?

Comment: Is it a rule that a reference to "it" would refer to the phrase preceding it, in the english language ? How would one refer to the first clause instead.

Comment: You say that "it" refers to the subject of the main clause.  The main clause is  "A Terminal Interface is used to interact with the Operating System",  whose subject is "a terminal interface".  Thusly, "it" refers te the subject which is  "a terminal interface", and not "an operating system".

Comment: But I want something different.  "It" should refer to the "Operating System", which is not the subject of the sentence.

Comment: So it is good as I had it.  Glad to hear.